# Classifying images in mass with URLs and CSV file

Tags: export, import, dataset, machine-learning

I'm looking to train a image classifier with a large number of examples and categories (30,000 & 100). I would then import a file of image URLs that need to be classified, and export the results. I'm able to get good results with smaller training sets (these are not real URLs):

```
In[1]=trainingset=Classify[{Import["www.url.com/asdf.jpg"]-> "category 1", 
    Import["www.url.com/qwer.jpg"]-> "category 2", 
    Import["www.url.com/1234.jpg"]-> "category 3",
    ET AL
    },Method->"RandomForest"]
Out[1]=ClassifierFuntion[Feature type: Image
    Number of examples: 70]
```

I would like to continue to use this Import["url"] method, and I would like to use a CSV because I have so much available training data. Is there a way to use the import function in a CSV for image URLs?

The following simple code is how I want it to work.

```
trainingset=Import["file1","CSV"]

imageclassifier[Classify[{trainingset},Method->"RandomForest"]]

needscategory=Import["file2","CSV"]

imageclassifier[needscategory]

Export["results","CSV"]
```

How should I structure my code/CSV in order to import the URL as an image?

**UPDATE:**

@JasonB excellent explanation, thank you for breaking it down!

I was able to replicate your results perfectly. I was able to import a CSV of images needing classification using this method as well by editing out the directions for a second column in the 'table' line:

```
In[5]=needscategory=Import["needscategory.csv"];
    needscategory=Table[Import[needscategory[[n,1]]],{n,1,Length[needscategory]}]
Out[6]={(penguin.jpg),(pickle.jpg)}

In[7]=imageclassifier[%6]
Out[7]={Penguin,Penguin}
```

For those looking trying to replicate this for their own projects, my working code look like this:

```
imglist=Import["test.csv"]
trainingset=Table[Import[imglist[[n,1]]]->imglist[[n,2]],{n,1,Length[imglist]}]
imageclassifier=Classify[trainingset,Method->"RandomForest"]

    ClassifierFunction[Method: RandomForest, Number of Classes: 2]

needscategory=Import["needscategory.csv"];
needscategory=Table[Import[needscategory[[n,1]]],{n,1,Length[needscategory]}]
```

The last step I want to take is to export my results as a CSV in the following format:

Column 1, Column 2
testimageURL1, result1
testimageURL2, result2

I am able to export the test image URLs separately:

```
Export["imageurls.csv", %6]
```

but I'm having trouble exporting the results:

```
Export["results.csv",%7]
```

Assuming it's possible to export results, how would I structure my Export line to combine both the original URLs and the results of the classifier?

Comment: So you already have the URLs in CSV format?  Like on each line there is an URL and a catagory name, separated by a comma?  It's hard to say how to best do this without an example, even if it only had a small number of URLs

Comment: Hard to format in this comment, but my training file looks like this:  Column 1:    Import["http://www.partstown.com/is-bin/intershop.static/WFS/Reedy-PartsTown-Site/-/en_US/products/renamed/shotfarm/medium/TRI_STAR_MANUFACTURING_SWITCH_ROCKER_ON_OFF_10A_250V-TRS340284.jpg"], Column 2: "Switches & Dials"

Comment: I just happened to reopen this and saw the new question, but it might not have been seen.  Generally here, the questions should be separate and self-contained, so that if one question is answered and you have a followup, you could post it as a new question.  Sometimes the new question might be too minor for a post of its own, and then the chatroom linked at the bottom is a good place for it.  You might not have enough reputation to go to the chat, but I think you could get more by doing some of the things in the [tour].

Comment: As to your current question, try to get the URLs for the images you need categorized into a list, like "needsCategories = {"http://.....", "http://......",.....}` Then you can `Map` the classifying function onto this list with just one line,  `classifiedCategories = imageclassifier /@ needsCategories`.  So now, `needsCategories` and `classifiedCategories` are both lists of strings.  You can convert them into a table and export to CSV via `Export["results.csv", Transpose[ { needsCategories , classifiedCategories} ]]`

Comment: @JasonB I checked out the tour and will complete it, thank you for that recommendation. I will post my follow up as a new question. I wasn't quite able to map them onto one line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say this is your CSV file,

```
http://i.imgur.com/8giNhRb.jpg, penguins
http://i.imgur.com/ZQXCY7c.jpg, penguins
http://i.imgur.com/bQ6lqNU.jpg, penguins
http://i.imgur.com/lxzTgH9.jpg, penguins
http://i.imgur.com/eHdgXnt.jpg, penguins
http://i.imgur.com/Bmy54vW.jpg, penguins
http://i.imgur.com/MtzebxR.jpg, penguins
http://i.imgur.com/pkDhR1w.jpg, penguins
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bb/Pickle.jpg, pickles
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c7/Og%C3%B3rki_kiszone.jpg, pickles
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Pickled_fruits_and_veggies.jpg, pickles
```

When I use `Import` to get this into *Mathematica*, it automatically parses it as an array, and the individual items are recognized as strings,

```
imglist = Import["test.csv"]

(* {{"http://i.imgur.com/8giNhRb.jpg", " penguins"}, 
    {"http://i.imgur.com/ZQXCY7c.jpg", " penguins"}, 
    {"http://i.imgur.com/bQ6lqNU.jpg", " penguins"}, 
     .....} *)
```

Now I want to convert this to the form that `Classify` wants, which I can do using `Table`,

```
trainingset = Table[Import[imglist[[n, 1]]] -> imglist[[n, 2]], {n, 1, 
  Length[imglist]}]
```

or, using a bit of shorthand this can be achieved using [pure functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html) and [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html),

```
trainingset = Import[#1] -> #2 & @@@ imglist
```

Both of these give the following output,

[image]

Now you create the classifier function as you wish,

```
imageclassifier = Classify[trainingset, Method -> "RandomForest"]
```

[image]

However, you may need more images, as this training set did not achieve good results,

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @JasonB! I would not have guessed that syntax.

Comment: @JonathanKolar Later I can break it down and explain what it all does, so check back tomorrow if you like

Answer (score 1):

Note that your use of `Table` introduces substantial syntactical overhead.  You can do better with `Map`.

Instead of

```
Table[
  Import[imglist[[n, 1]]] -> imglist[[n, 2]], 
  {n, 1, Length[imglist]}
]
```

you can

```
Import[#[[1]]] -> #[[2]] & /@ imglist
```

or even better

```
Import@#1 -> #2 & @@@ imglist
```